# Leaves from tree sticking to new outside caulk

Tags: caulking

[image]
I had a person recaulk my patio cement where it meet a brick retainer will last week, he did it about 12 hrs before it rained. He said it was the best on the market and it would be fine with a few showers after 8 hrs.
Well after 3 days of rain and blowing wind with leaves falling & the caulk still very tacky, the leaves are stuck to the caulk. I would rather not try to pick out the leaves, don't want to break the caulk skin.
Can I remove these leaves next spring/summer?
I live in Michigan, so it is just going to get colder and colder. The caulk guy is no where to be found. I invested $1300 total. He was supposed to be a handyman. I call a few professionals and they did not even want the job, said it was too small. It is so hard to get someone to do small repairs. I am 75 now and there are things I just can't do myself anymore.
Thank You very much for any opinions. Gary

Comment: Could you post a photo of a section of caulk with leaves stuck on it to clarify what you're dealing with? For example, what type of caulk? In general, I don't think it will get any easier to remove debris as the caulk cures.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Just came in the house, added a photo.

Comment: if you cannot remove the leaves now, then you will not be able to remove them later

Comment: Most of the leaves will rot away over winter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could consider using some chalk powder, they even come in colors.

You can spray/spread it over, to absorb the moisture and speed up curing.

Comment: Thank you. The skin is all ready dry, will I be able to pick out the leafs after it fully cures?

Comment: great, so ignore my answer, was just trying to help fellow 75

Comment: Not ignoring your answer. After putting down the chalk when will I be able to remove the leafs?

Comment: Thank you to everyone who replied....I will et it sorted.